# change action name depending of dropdownlist value MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to change the action name according to the dropdownlist value?

Here is the dropdownlist

```
@{Html.DropDownList("import", @ViewData["list"] as SelectList)}
```

And the form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(dropdownlist.value(), "Files", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Not with out a post back to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it in the client side. try this.

```
  @{Html.DropDownList("import", @ViewData["list"] as SelectList)}

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('select[name=import]').change(function () {
            document.formsame.action = "controllerName" + $(this).val();
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to accomplish this. One is using Jquery to handle the selection event and controller call. This requires some design decisions such as if it will be an AJAX call or not. Another solution that can be implemented client side and follows the methodology you already started using is the following:

```
Html.DropDownList("import", ViewData["list"] as SelectList, 
                new 
                { 
                    onchange = @"
                    var form = document.forms[0]; 
                    form.action='controllerName';
                    form.submit();" 
                } )
```

Finally, I haven't tested it and I am not certain that it is considered good practice, but you could probably handle this server side by having a default controller that takes these drop down menus and decides how to redirect them. Pretty sure this would be frowned upon as a best practice since you are doing some business logic in the generic control layer, but it may work for your purposes?